# Symfony2 Checkbox List

Tags: symfony, checkbox

I have a Many to Many relation in my project but I want to modify my relation table, so I converted it into a two Many to One relation with the join table on another entity.

The problem is that when I try to render a checkbox group of the en two initial entities I'm not able to use then.

Here is my code:

```
class Professional extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

...

/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="professional")
     */
    private $turns;

...
```

My second entity

```
class Turn
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
...

  /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="turn")
     */
    private $professionals;

...
```

And the join entity

```
class TurnsProfessional
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Turn", inversedBy="professionals")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="turn_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $turn;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professional", inversedBy="turns")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $professional;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $status = 0;
 ...
```

My goal is to create a checkbox list in the Professional form with the turns. I've tried two things:

First I've tried to add in the ProfessionalType the field as a Turn::class:

```
...
 ->add('turns', 'entity',
            array('class' => 'AppBundle:TurnsProfessional',
                'property' => 'label',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                ));
...
```

The problem here is that the form does not render the checkboxes. Otherwise if I change the class:

```
...
->add('turns', 'entity',
            array('class' => 'AppBundle:Turn',
                'property' => 'label',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                ));
...
```

The form does render all the checkboxes but i get an error on sending it:

> Found entity of type AppBundle\Entity\Turn on association
>   AppBundle\Entity\Professional#turns, but expecting
>   AppBundle\Entity\TurnsProfessional

I´ve edited the form as Oliver said (on comments):

```
->add($builder->create('turns', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => TurnsProfessionalType::class,
            'by_reference' => false,
        )));
```

With the TurnsProfessionalType

```
class TurnsProfessionalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  
        $builder
        ->add('status')
        ->add('turn', EntityType::class,
            array('class' => 'AppBundle:Turn',
                'property' => 'label',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
             ));

    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'turns_professional_registration_form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => TurnsProfessional::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Now I've rendered it as:

```
 {% for turn in form.turns %}
      <td><div class="checkbox">{{ form_widget(turn.status)}}<label></label></div></td>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I need to put as label the database label of each turn

Does anyone can help?
Thank you!

Comment: You should use a [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/collection.html) instead of an EntityType and have a look at symfony doc on [how to embed a collection of forms](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: @OlivierC Should I use a CollectionType of Turn, or TurnsProfessional?

Comment: A CollectionType of TurnsProfessionalType having a EntityType field taking a Turn entity

Comment: @OlivierC Thank you, I´ve managed to go this way, the problem is that I cant get acces to the label of the turn, for making able to render it. And now I have the form rendered on a select with all the database columns.

Comment: What is your symfony version, so i can write a proper answer

Comment: @OlivierC It's Symfony 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Professional Entity

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="professional", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $turns;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->turns = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add turn
 *
 * @param  TurnsProfessional $turns
 * @return Professional
 */
public function addTurn(TurnsProfessional $turn)
{
    /*
      Doctrine only checks the owning side(ManyToOne). So you
      need to manually call the join entity setter to keep
      your data in sync.
    */
    $turn->setProfessional($this);
    $this->turns->add($turn);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove turn
 *
 * @param  TurnsProfessional $turn
 * @return Professional
 */
public function removeTurn(TurnsProfessional $turn)
{
    /*
      Doctrine only checks the owning side(ManyToOne). So you
      need to manually call the join entity setter to keep
      your data in sync.
    */
    $turn->setProfessional();
    $this->turns->removeElement($turn);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get turns
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTurns()
{
    return $this->turns;
}
```

Turn Entity

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="turn", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $professionals;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->professionals = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add professional
 *
 * @param TurnsProfessional $professional
 * @return Turn
 */
public function addProfessional(TurnsProfessional $professional)
{
    /*
      Doctrine only checks the owning side(ManyToOne). So you
      need to manually call the join entity setter to keep
      your data in sync.
    */
    $professional->setTurn($this);
    $this->professionals->add($professional);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove professional
 *
 * @param TurnsProfessional $professional
 * @return Turn
 */
public function removeProfessional(TurnsProfessional $professional)
{
    /*
      Doctrine only checks the owning side(ManyToOne). So you
      need to manually call the join entity setter to keep
      your data in sync.
    */
    $professional->setTurn();
    $this->professional->removeElement($professional);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get professionals
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getProfessionals()
{
    return $this->professionals;
}
```

TurnsProfessional Entity

```
/**
 * @var Professional
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Professional", inversedBy="turns", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $professional;

/**
 * @var Turn
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Turn", inversedBy="professionals", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $turn;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
 */
private $status = true; //You should set a default value to true, since it is non sense to create some value if it not active

/**
 * Set professional
 *
 * @param Professional $professional
 * @return TurnsProfessional
 */
public function setProfessional(Professional $professional = null)
{
    /*
      Using a default null value allows you to unset of the value of
      the joined entity when removing in inverse side
      (see removeTurn in Professional entity)
    */
    $this->professional = $professional;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set turn
 *
 * @param Turn $turn
 * @return TurnsProfessional
 */
public function setTurn(Turn $turn = null)
{
    /*
      Using a default null value allows you to unset of the value of
      the joined entity when removing in inverse side
      (see removeProfessional in Turn entity)
    */
    $this->turn = $turn;

    return $this;
}
```

ProfessionalType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Form\TurnsProfessionalType;

class ProfessionalType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('turns', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => TurnsProfessionalType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false, //with by_reference at false you force the call of the setter
        ))
            //other fields
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Professional',
            'cascade_validation => true //will also validate joined entities
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'turns_professional_registration_form';
    }
}
```

TurnsProfessionalType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Turn;

class TurnsProfessionalType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('turn', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'   => Turn::class,
            'choice_label' => 'label'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TypesProfessional'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'turns_professional_registration_form';
    }
}
```

twig template

```
/*
  By default you will have an empty turns collection which
  which means you will get no field displayed
  that's why you need a addTurn button to fill your collection
  and add fields to your form
*/ 
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <ul class="turns" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.turns.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
        {% for turn in form.turns %}
            <li>{{ form_row(turn.turn) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script>
    var $collectionHolder;

    // setup an "add a turn" link
    var $addTurnLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_turn_link">Add a turn</a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTurnLink);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Get the ul that holds the collection of turns
        $collectionHolder = $('ul.turns');

        // add the "add a turn" anchor and li to the turns ul
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

        // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
        // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

        $addTurnLink.on('click', function(e) {
            // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
            e.preventDefault();

            // add a new turn form (see next code block)
            addTurnForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });

    function addTurnForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
        var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

        // get the new index
        var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

        // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
        // instead be a number based on how many items we have
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

        // increase the index with one for the next item
        $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

        // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a turn" link li
        var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
        $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should add some explainations.