# EntityType: Charge all the values available even thought if the option is not set

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have three entities running in Symfony:

Professional

```
class Professional extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="professional")
     */
    private $turns;

}
```

Turn

```
class Turn
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TurnsProfessional", mappedBy="turn")
     */
    private $professionals;

}
```

TurnsProfessionals

```
class TurnsProfessional
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Turn", inversedBy="professionals")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="turn_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $turn;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professional", inversedBy="turns")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $professional;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;

}
```

In the FormType I have this:

```
->add('turns', 'entity',
     array('class' => 'AppBundle:TurnsProfessional',
          'property' => 'label',
          'multiple' => true,
          'expanded' => true,
));
```

What I would like to do is load all the "turns" available in "Turn" entity (Monday morning, Monday evening, Tuesday morning, etc.) and show them like checkboxes in a form. If the turn is checked, the turn will be registered in TurnsProfessional with status = 1 and if not with status = 0.

When I have all the turns saved in TurnsProfessional with status = 0 or status = 1, Symfony print all the options right and everything works. But, the first time no turn are created for the professional so the add('turns') method returns an empty value with no checkboxes.

How could I show all the options available in Turn entity in this case?

Thanks!

#### UPDATE FormType

I've tried to add a query_builder option in the FormType:

```
->add('turns', EntityType::class,
    array('class' => 'AppBundle:Turn',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('turn')
                    ->orderBy('turn.id', 'ASC');
        },
          'choice_label' => 'label',
          'multiple'=>true,
          'expanded'=>true,
 ))
```

Now, the form shows all the options but when I try to save the form I get the following error:

> Found entity of type AppBundle\Entity\Turn on association
>   AppBundle\Entity\Professional#turns, but expecting
>   AppBundle\Entity\TurnsProfessional

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, the form will be empty because there are no `TurnsProfessional` set for this `Professional` at this point. And you want to know how you can solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/41825066/7169909

Comment: @KhorneHoly yes, that is

Comment: @KhorneHoly I added a new code which load all the options but then I get an error because the entity is different :S

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because your entity is waiting for a TurnsProfessional object and you are trying to give it a Turn object. To solve this you should not map directly the field to your entity:

```
->add('turns', EntityType::class,
    array('class' => 'AppBundle:Turn',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('turn')
                    ->orderBy('turn.id', 'ASC');
        },
          'choice_label' => 'label',
          'multiple' => true,
          'expanded' => true,
          'mapped' => false
 ))
```

Then in your controller you can access to the result like this:

```
$turns = $form->get('turns);
```

But you have to keep in mind that $turns will only contains the Turn entities you selected in your form.